# how to know what Wireless access point is used by a windows workstation

Tags: windows, wifi

I have multiple access points serving the same SSID. When some workstations experience WIFI issues, I need to know remotely what AP is currently being used to I can look at its state and maybe reboot it.
I would rather have a solution that relies on running powershell script on the workstation, but I can also live with looking at things on the AP's

Comment: Who is your wireless vendor? Any wireless product worth using will have a central console that allows you to see this, but how you go about it will be different for each vendor.

Comment: Thanks Joel. Would be more convenient for me to get that info from running a PowerShell from the workstation, but your response helps

Answer (score 0):

I know you said remotely, but that makes things a bit difficult. Maybe you can have someone at that location assist?

I honestly would do this manually, but I'm articulate that way. Physically locate all of the WAP's. If possible, and if they have an ethernet port, plug a laptop in there and note the gateway, that will tell you the IP address of the WAP.

If this is not possible, you're definitely going to have to do it manually. Run a LAN scan and note all the WAP devices in the list. Make notes of where they physically are and have someone unplug the WAP one by one, then re-run the LAN scan; the one missing is the one unplugged.

Comment: So, this would tell me what are the IP's of my AP's. Does this help me knowing which one is used by a given workstation?

Comment: It will tell you the IP's of your WAP's, yes. If you want to know which user is using which WAP, they would have to do an ipconfig and check out the address for the gateway, that will tell you which WAP is having issues. Or, if you know where they physically are, you can manage that one.